# PythonAnywhere cannot get site to redirect without www

Tags: django, pythonanywhere

Whenever I try to access my pythonanywhere django site without "www." in front it redirects to the pythonanywhere "COMING SOON! This is going to be another great website hosted by PythonAnywhere." landing page.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [u'webapp-******.pythonanywhere.com',
u'******.pythonanywhere.com',
u'******.co.uk',
u'www.******.co.uk']
```

Anyone encountered and solved this before?

Comment: `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`

Comment: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/13844/

Comment: @c.grey That's the opposite way round and the answer doesn't help me :(

Comment: you should setup a redirect from your domain registration provider / dns provider so that your root domain (without www) redirects to www.yourdomain.com.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have a web app without www, then there is no site there, so you'll get the Coming Soon page.